# Statement to determine the type of an object in C++

Tags: c++, types

Is there a statement s_type which allows to determine the type of an object in C++?

E.g.

```
s_type(int a);      // int
s_type(&a);         // int*
```

Comment: `<type_traits>`. There are ways to print the type, but prefer boost when it comes to that.

Comment: Hello @sweenish can you write an example please?

Comment: [There](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) you go...

Comment: Do you want to print the type, or do something else with it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, i want only to print them

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 what is the statement for the integers?

Comment: @ArdentCoder the compiler gives me the error: ‘type_name’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @FedericaGuidotti I followed the top answer in that post and I got your expected results: [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4EsKhD).

Comment: @ArdentCoder great code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;
  using std::cout;

  int a = 42;
  int& b = a;
  int* c = &a;

  cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(a)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
  cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(b)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
  cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(c)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
}
```

Output is:

```
int  
int&  
int*
```

If I want to see the types, this is the method I use. It does require boost and some people don't like to see third-party libraries, but this does the job much better than C++'s `typeid`.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `decltype`:

```cpp
int a = 0;
decltype(a) b = 42;
```

Comment: how can i print it?

Comment: @FedericaGuidotti Types cannot be printed in C++. You can get something out of `typeid`.

Comment: @eerorika can you show me an example for an int object please?

Comment: @FedericaGuidotti: You cannot print a typename; whatever you might get out of `typeid` will be implementation-defined and is almost certainly not the human-readable C++ name of the type. At present, this is not a thing that's possible in C++.

Comment: ... without some extra effort.